# How to keep the separator when using regexp.split

Tags: javascript

**First question** - 
Will the following split code works to split a value which is delimited/separated by random symbol? I mean any possible symbol?

```
value.split(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/g);
```

I want to find a simple regex that works to split on any characters in any value, like for example the set of data below

> - xx-yy-zz
> - xx/yy/zz
> - xx\yy\zz
> - xx*yy*zz
> - xx_yy_zz
> - xx^yy^zz
> - And any other combinations

**Second question** - 
Say if i used the regex on the first question to split each data, how can i know what symbol that was used to split for each data? I want to keep the symbol if can because i might want to use it again to join the xx, yy and zz again.

Comment: Actually, if you make the regex like `value.split(/([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/])/g)`, I think you can get the symbol also. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/yUvqC/). If this is what you want, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: [just saying] you can also use `match` instead of `split` here. like this -- `("xx-yy-zz").match(/[^-!$%^&*()_+|~=\`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]+/g);`.

Comment: So like if i do var value = ("xx-yy-zz").match(/[^-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]+/g); , will i be able to get the delimiter symbol used in the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question - I don't see any reason why not. Try before asking.

Second question - This will add split character into resulting array -

```
/([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/])/g
```

then `xx-xx^xx&xx` will turn into `['xx', '-', 'xx', '^', 'xx', '&', 'xx' ]`

Other way is to iterate over regexp matches istead of splitting at once

Comment: I tried this code
_date = date.split(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/g);

And the data i used was dd-mm-yyyy
But after split, i got only ["dd", "mm", "yyyy", readUInt8: function, readUInt16LE: function, readInt16LE: function, readUInt32LE: function, readDoubleLE: function…] on the inspector. It didn't show the symbol on the array. Did i missed anything?

Comment: @FredA: Did you try the fiddle I had posted in the comments (below the question)? It is basically the same as SergeS' answer.